# Django-admin collectstatic is an unknown command

Tags: django

Trying to collect my static files as I will be deploying my website soon. Receiving:

```
Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
```

After checking django-admin help I receive this warning:

```
(error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. 
 You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
 settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

Here is my manage.py:

```
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'xwordsite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I have tried running manage.py shell, which did not solve the issue.
Also I'm unsure if it matters but all my static files are in the project dir.
Also static settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/xwordsite/static"
```

Comment: What command did you issue?

Comment: django-admin collectstatic

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: omg I'm a muppet Ty

Comment: I've added a answer, please accept it if it worked ;D

Comment: was it by chance running the command `django-admin collectstatic` that raised your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#console-block-0):

Just write `python manage.py collectstatic` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

[In this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic), at first says `django-admin collectstatic` but end of the section there is a code block that says `manage.py collectstatic`. At first it confused me. I did try to solve this error and tried to configure settings etc. which did not worked.

After all these effort, suddenly it hit me and i wrote `manage.py collectstatic` and it worked.